# When you call someone, do you say "Is this Mr Smith?" or "Is that Mr Smith?" when that person picks up?

Tags: grammar, demonstratives, telephone, deixis

I feel it should be *this* since am talking to the very same person, but for some reason I see some people saying “Is **that** XYZ?”

What are your thoughts about this bit of phone etiquette?

Comment: It is regional thing: in UK we ask "is that XYZ?" People would think it strange if they answer the phone and the caller doesn't know their own identity. It would be like "Am I XYZ?"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In answering a telephone call, why do you say "Who is this?" instead of "Who is that?"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/123009/in-answering-a-telephone-call-why-do-you-say-who-is-this-instead-of-who-is) // "Who is this, please?" is the way I usually deal with an unsolicited and as yet anonymous call. And I live in the UK too, @Weather Vane. We have a choice of deictic centre.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. To my American ear, both sound overly direct for a cold call. *Hello, may I speak to Mr. Smith, please? This is X.* or *Hello, this is X. Is Mr. Smith available?* would be more polite. If you are calling somewhere familiar, *this* or *that* might be used in an endearing way if, for example, a child is answering the phone (*Hello, is that Morty? My, you sound so grown up. Is your dad home?*). Since there is no context given and the question is a solicitation for opinions, however, I must vote to close.

Answer (score 0):

This certainly has regional and national differences.

In my case (US English), the most common phrasing is:

"Hello, is this Mr. Smith?"

Also common:

"Hello, are you Mr. Smith?"

"Hello, I'm calling for Mr. Smith"

"Hello, is Mr. Smith there?"

"Hello, I'm trying to reach Mr. Smith."

Comment: "I'd like to speak to Mr Smith."  "May I speak to Mr Smith."

Comment: Yes, absolutely, both examples I would consider common and polite.