# Why is "these" preferred in academic writing to "those?"

Tags: determiners

for academic writing

The drugs have other inactive ingredients such as galactose, rhodamine,
and hexylene glycol. Exactly why these ingredients remain inactive has
yet to be determined.

Question: Why do we use "these" ingredients rather than "those"?

Comment: If you were going to mention those ingredients later, _those_ would work. But this is just an "et cetera" reference, it looks like, and _these_ keeps it close and dispensable.

Comment: This is a very good question. That said, the previous comment is absolutely correct. And, no, this has nothing to do at all with academic writing per se.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In answering a telephone call, why do you say "Who is this?" instead of "Who is that?"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/123009/in-answering-a-telephone-call-why-do-you-say-who-is-this-instead-of-who-is)

Answer (score 2):

You use "these" for things that are closer or "at hand", like "these ingredients..." you just named.

Whereas "those" refers to something that is abstract, not close, general.

Correct me if I’m wrong. I’m not a native speaker but an English teacher here in Germany.

To my students I explain it with the situation in a shoe shop.
You go in and take the first shoes you like, hold the pair in your hands and say "I like these shoes." But then you see another pair in a shelf which is at the other  end of the Shop and you point to them and say "But I also like those shoes over there."

It's the same with "this" and "that" in singular.

Comment: With the shoe-shop example, the choice is easy (within 3 feet vs 20 feet away for smallish concrete items). With metaphorical (non-concrete) usages, you have a choice. On the phone, often "Who is this, please?" so as not to distance the caller. With OP's example, the choice of 'these', to paraphrase John Lawler's comment, focuses the addressee's thoughts on the conundrum (under the spotlight rather than on the back-burner).